# Simulating gamepad hardware signals

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

I'm trying to write a script to simulate a gamepad, for testing purposes.

I've used the `inputs` library to capture the signals being sent by the gamepad but I'm at a loss when it comes to sending those signals to the computer to interpret (i.e. make the computer press <kbd>A</kbd> for me).

Code:

```
while 1:
    events = get_gamepad()
    for event in events:
        print(event.ev_type, event.code, event.state)
```

Result:

```
Absolute ABS_RY -210
Sync SYN_REPORT 0
Absolute ABS_HAT0X -1
Sync SYN_REPORT 0
Absolute ABS_HAT0X 0
Sync SYN_REPORT 0
Key BTN_SOUTH 1
Sync SYN_REPORT 0
Key BTN_SOUTH 0
Sync SYN_REPORT 0
Absolute ABS_RY -274
Sync SYN_REPORT 0
```

This resulted from me pressing left on the d-pad and the <kbd>A</kbd> button.

I was able to make a script using `pynput` which lets me type as follows:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

kb = Controller()

#time before typing
time.sleep(4)

kb.press('h')
kb.release('h')
kb.press('e')
kb.release('e')
kb.press('l')
kb.release('l')
kb.press('l')
kb.release('l')
kb.press('o')
kb.release('o')
```

So my question is:

How do I send (for example) a press of the <kbd>A</kbd> button using a similar method?

Comment: Wait, just to clarify, you're trying to essentially simulate a gamepad?

Comment: @Axium a piece of hardware, not necessarily a gamepad, but yes.
I essentially want to do something like:
python.sendSignal('Absolute ABS_RY -210')

Comment: i've only found something for gamepads, so this might be something useful to look at: https://github.com/tidzo/pyvjoy
It essentially is python bindings for a program that seems to be able to simulate gamepad presses. Maybe not like how you've written though.

Comment: Yeah, I stumbled on that myself but it's not quite what I'm looking for; I want to send more generic hardware signals and used a gamepad as an example, for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Your code modified

def method_a():
    # do something here, maybe react on
    # an additional parameter for press/release
    pass


def method_b():
    pass


while 1:
    events = get_gamepad()
    for event in events:
        print(event.ev_type, event.code, event.state)
        if event.code == "A":
            method_a()
        if event.code == "B":
            method_b()

# testing: run indirectly the methods of your 
# business logic to mock the hardware

# unittests or similar here

def test_method_aba():
    method_a()
    method_b()
    method_a()
    # check state, do assertions
```

Comment: I appreciate the response but I actually want to send the same signal as pressing 'A' on the controller would. I do not want to define actions based on pressing the button on the controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
class my_event:
    def __init__(self, code, ev_type, state):
        self.code = code
        self.ev_type = ev_type
        self.state = state


def get_gamepad_mocked():
    event_list = []
    event_list.append(my_event(code="A", state="press"))
    event_list.append(my_event(code="A", state="release"))
    event_list.append(my_event(code="B", state="press"))
    return event_list


while 1:
    events = get_gamepad_mocked()
    for event in events:
        print(event.ev_type, event.code, event.state)
```

You need to add the expected value of `ev_type`. Dont have hardware here to test that.

Comment: This does not answer the question as it only prints out the signals instead of implementing them. It literally repeats the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what OS you are intending this for, but there is a great library for generating keyboard / mouse events in Python called PyUserInput.

[https://github.com/PyUserInput/PyUserInput ]

```
from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard
k = PyKeyboard()

k.press_key('H')
```

Comment: It's not events that I'm looking to handle. I want to create events, without the use of the hardware itself. I've been using pynput to do what you are suggesting (in case you ever want an alternative.

Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: This does what you want. It is not watching for a keypress, it is generating one. Do I not understand correctly?

Comment: It doesn't do what I want for the hardware I'm looking to simulate; you are right though I misinterpreted what you said. If I wanted to simulate a keyboard/mouse it would in fact work. I am looking to simulate "X" hardware; I used a game controller as an example but really I want to send the signal which tells the computer "I pressed this button" without actually pressing one.